# Find the Average of digits by using While Loop

Tags: java

I know this is basis problem, but I just can't solve this, so I need your help..
I am trying to find the average of digits of the number(user input) by using While Loop, like for example, the average of digits of the number 789 is (7+8+9+)/3 = 8. 
Could anyone help me with this..? Thank you so much.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AVE
{

  static int digits = 0;
  static int average =0;
  static int sum =0;
  static int number;


  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("what is your number?");
    number = kb.nextInt();
    avDigits();
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
  }

  public static void avDigits()
  {
    int num = number;
    while (num > 0)
    {
      digits += 1;
      sum += digits % 10;
      num/=10;
    }

    average = (sum/digits);

   }
}
```

Comment: How do you guarantee that average is representable by an Integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with the mod. You can rewrite the code as follows, Modification is done not only to correct the error but to make standardized. You need to change average to float or double.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AVE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        float average = 0;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what is your number?");
        number = kb.nextInt();
        average = avDigits(number);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
    private static float avDigits(int number) {
        int digits = 0;
        float sum = 0.0F;
        while (number > 0) {
            digits += 1;
            sum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return (sum / digits);
    }
}
```

Comment: i do agree with this answer

Answer (score 1):

You are taking mod of `digits` instead of `num`. Change the while loop as following:

```
 while (num > 0)
{
  digits += 1;
  sum += num % 10;  //<< Take mod of num here
  num/=10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class AVE
{

  static int digits = 0;
  static float average =0;
  static int sum =0;
  static int number;


  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("what is your number?");
    number = kb.nextInt();
    avDigits();
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
  }

  public static void avDigits()
  {
    int num = number;
    while (num > 0)
    {
      digits += 1;
      sum += num % 10;  /*Do the modulo of num instead of digit. Since doing the modulo of num will give you the last digit*/
      num/=10;
    }

    average = ((float)sum/digits);  //average can be in decimal also

   }
}
```

Comment: The changes wherever needed, I have commented them in the code please see them.